# CSS Keyframe to animate element to top of page

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I want to animate an element to the top of my page. This is how it goes:

HTML:

```
...
<ion-row id="theHistory"></ion-row>
...
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes floatBubble {
    0% {
        top:??;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
.element-up{
    z-index:10;
    background-color:white;

    -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s infinite  normal ease-out;
    animation: floatBubble 2s infinite  normal ease-out;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
scrollToHistory.classList.add('element-up')
```

What value should i put in top to take the current position of ion-row? Or i have to do this in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like @Temani's solution, but mine uses `transform`, which creates a smoother animation than `top`. Using `transform/translate` the box will be promoted to its own render layer.

I assign the box's offset to a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and `translate` the box using the offset value stored in the `CSS` variable `--move-y`.

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
box.addEventListener("click", move);

function move(e) {
  const distanceFromTop = (this.offsetTop * -1) + "px";
  this.style.setProperty("--move-y", distanceFromTop);
  this.classList.add("element-up");
}
```

```css
@keyframes floatBubble {
  to {
    transform: translateY(var(--move-y, 0));
  }
}

div.element-up {
  z-index: 10;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orvcn7y3/

Comment: better set the custom property on the element instead of the root so that it can work with any element ... you can also get rid of the definition in the CSS and use the default value `var(--c,0)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks (updated). Didn't realize I could forgo the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using JS you can set the `top` property dynamically and no need to add anything to the keyframes:

```js
function move(e) {
  e.style.top = e.offsetTop + "px";
  e.classList.add('element-up');
}
```

```css
@keyframes floatBubble {
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}

div.element-up {
  z-index: 10;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

body {
 margin:0;
 padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="move(this)">
</div>
```